# Set Workshop Filters' default value

Tags: filter, palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

When we define a filter in Workshop, the output object set is used to apply users' filter options to another widget.
But it's also mentioned in the documentation that setting this variable is a mean to provide et default value: how does it actually work? I mean, how to shall I do to set this variable (I do not even know how to put a static value) with, for instance, the output of another widget (let's say a multi select table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of a Filter List widget in Workshop is a *filter*-type variable. To get an Object Set that reflects this filter, you then create a separate *Object Set*-type variable and use the configuration option there to choose one or more filter-type variables to apply.

To set the defaults of the filter so that they show up as selections in the Filter List, you can edit the default configuration for the *for the output filter variable*. First you have to choose the object type to which the filter corresponds and then you'll have access to the various properties of that object type. You can set a static default or you can choose a "typed" Variable (string, number, date, timestamp) and make that the default.

You can then get creative about where *those* variables are sourced from to wire together dynamic default selections for the Filter List values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works! Even if, to be honest, I'm still looking for setting multiple values, coming from a multi select widget

Comment: I got it! I had to create an *array* variable as an aggregation of a property, the identify the output object set and choose "unique value" of the selected property.